# Customizing Swagger Code Gen and SwashbuckleUI in .NET Core API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger

I have a .NET Core Api project with OpenAPI/Swagger via the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` library, I'm trying to implement some customizations on the generated schemas for my response model classes, and ultimately have that data displayed out in the Model section in the SwashbuckleUI page.

My response model classes are extensively documented with some custom XML tags with information discovered about the formatting and possible values of the data from the original data source (among other things).

```cs
public MyClassDTO
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Property Description.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Responses containing values of "X" mean one thing, "Y" another, etc... aka user-friendly and easily understood.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <original_info_painfully_discovered_along_the_way>
    /// <possible_values>X, Y, Z, 10 for some reason, AA, MM</possible_values>
    /// <always_available_in_original_dataset>false - removed if null</always_available_in_original_dataset>
    /// </original_info_painfully_discovered_along_the_way>
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
}
```

The swagger.json file currently looks something like:

```json
"schemas": {
    "MyClassDTO": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties: {
           "propertyName": {
              "type": "string",
              "description": "Property Description",
              "nullable": true
           }
        }
    }
}
```

I am hoping to get it to contain the extra documentation:

```json
"schemas": {
    "MyClassDTO": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties: {
           "propertyName": {
              "type": "string",
              "description": "Property Description",
              "nullable": true,
              "original_info_painfully_discovered_along_the_way": {
                  "possible_values": "X, Y, Z, 10 for some reason, AA, MM"
                  "always_available_in_original_dataset": "false - removed if null"
              }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm assuming I will need to either provide a custom schema for my model classes in the swagger gen configuration or extend something, but I can't find exactly what that is.

On the UI side, I'm assuming I'll have to supply a custom index.html page and rework that to read the custom swagger.json file? But any pointers or articles for C# would be very helpful, as I couldn't find much on my own.

I have also noticed that the remarks field does not make it out into the swagger.json file or the UI- and some of my top level model classes contain detailed remarks fields with details on trends, etc.. in the datasets, so it would be nice to display those out as well.